# How to handle missing variables in R

Tags: r, missing-data

I need help writing R code which will:

- Detect missing variables from a dataframe
- Create a dummy variable to represent the missing variable
- Set the dummy variable to zero

Following is an example of the code I'm working on:

```
    # load library

    library(dplyr)

    # set variables

    a <- c("Jenny", "Jenny", "John", "Jenny", "John")
    b <- c(1,0,1,0,1)
    C <- c(0,1,1,1,0)

    # bind into dataframe

    dat <- cbind.data.frame(a, b, C)

    # subsequent imaginary code joins df to another dataset. The join is supposed to add   
    # another variable called "d". For whatever reason, d does not exist. 
    # So dat still only has three variables - a, b & c.

    # the script now runs an aggregating function 
    # but the aggregating function expects four variables - a, b, c & d

    dat_A <- dat %>% 
             group_by(a) %>% 
             summarise(b_new = sum(b),
                       c_new = sum(C),
                       d_new = sum(d))

   # because "d" is missing, R returns an error. I need code which will    
   # detect "d" is missing and create a dummy variable for this variable 
   # with zero value and bind to dat before aggregating.
```

Comment: Why don't use simple if to check whether all variables exist?

Comment: can you please provide an example of the output you're looking for?

Comment: Hi Kipras. I am already checking and replacing manually. But I need code that will automatically check and replace. This will allow my script to run without human intervention. The bigger picture is that at the end of my script, the model object expects a fixed number of variables. If any of these variables to do appear, my model doesn't run and returns an error.

Comment: Hi Cyrus. What I expect is code that will automatically detect that variable "d" is missing and create a dummy variable called "d" with zero value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check whether strings (representing column names you want) are in your data frame, and assign them to 0 if not as done in this example:

```
x <- data.frame(a = 1:5)  # Example data
x
#>   a
#> 1 1
#> 2 2
#> 3 3
#> 4 4
#> 5 5

to_check <- c("a", "b", "c")  # these are colum names to check for < CHANGE THIS

x[, setdiff(to_check, names(x))] <- 0  # this creates any missing columns as 0
x
#>   a b c
#> 1 1 0 0
#> 2 2 0 0
#> 3 3 0 0
#> 4 4 0 0
#> 5 5 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create a vector of names that we want to start with ('v1'), get the common elements in 'v1' with the column names of dataset ('Int'), elements that are only found in 'v1' ('setD').  Then, after grouping by 'a', we use `summarise_each` to get the `sum` of individual columns in 'Int', `cbind` with the 0 elements in 'setD'

```
v1 <- letters[2:8]
Int <- intersect(names(dat), v1)
setD <- setdiff(v1, names(dat))
dat %>% 
   group_by(a) %>%
   summarise_each_(funs(sum), Int) %>%
   cbind(., setNames(rep(list(0), length(setD)), setD))
#      a b c d e f g h
#1 Jenny 1 2 0 0 0 0 0
#2  John 2 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

---

We can also use `gather/spread` to do this automatically.  Reshape the dataset to 'long' format (`gather`), convert the 'Var' to `factor` class with `levels` specified as the column names that we want in the expected output, after grouping by 'a', 'Var', get the `sum` of 'Val' and then `spread` it back to 'wide' format with `drop = FALSE` and `fill = 0`.

```
library(tidyr)
dat %>%
    gather(Var, Val, -a) %>% 
    mutate(Var = factor(Var, levels = letters[2:8])) %>%
    group_by(a, Var) %>% 
    summarise(Val = sum(Val)) %>% 
    spread(Var, Val, drop = FALSE, fill = 0)
#       a     b     c     d     e     f     g     h
#    <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  Jenny     1     2     0     0     0     0     0
#2   John     2     1     0     0     0     0     0
```

#### data

```
dat <- data.frame(a = c("Jenny", "Jenny", "John", "Jenny", "John"),
                  b =  c(1,0,1,0,1),
                  c = c(0,1,1,1,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use an `if` statement. Since you mention that you want to add the variable in `dat` **before** aggregating then I would suggest,

```
if(!'d' %in% names(dat[,-1])) {dat$d <- 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if an R object is defined:

```
    if(exists("d")==TRUE)
                                {
                                sum(d)
                                }
     else
                                {
                                dat$d <- 0
                                sum(d)
                                }
```